# Baffled by Wi-Fi situation, TP-Link Archer T9UH weak connection and occasional disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-driver

Apologies in advance for what might be a long-winded post. I've been plagued by wifi issues for months now, and every time I think I have it working, something goes wrong. I'm also a complete novice with networking related issues, so this particular area of troubleshooting often leaves me baffled.

First, my issue: I have been having difficulty maintaining a steady connection. Sometimes I get an error saying I can't connect to the network, sometimes I connect but the speed is in the single digits, and sometimes I connect and get the ~150Mb/s I'm expecting, only to have the connection deteriorate and sometimes disconnect entirely over the next 30 minutes or so.

So far I've tried a few different things to hopefully narrow down what might be causing the issue, but again I'm a novice so I may have missed something. Starting with the more basic stuff, I've unplugged/plugged in the adapter itself. This occasionally gives me a brief moment of high quality connection, but as I mentioned it never seems to last.

I've also tried doing things like flushing the dns cache and a few other cmd lines that are supposed to help clear up any issues from that angle.

To add an even more confusing wrinkle, I also have a wifi extender that's closer to my PC, and for whatever reason I'm able to connect to the extender without having the connection drop and fluctuate. The only problem there is the extender can only provide ~10-15 Mb/s, and I really only got it to help watch media on my tablet which seems to have a weak wifi antenna and can't reach the router downstairs.

Getting back to my PC's wifi adapter, I also have tried to do a clean install of the driver because I happened to get a troubleshooter error about a driver being problematic, but have only received that error once (because why would anything be consistent with an issue like this...). However, I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to do in that regard. I went into device manager, found my adapter, clicked uninstall device, restarted, and when I booted back up and ran the driver installation, it said I already had the driver installed and I would need to uninstall it first, so... maybe I'm missing something obvious there, but it left me baffled.

tl;dr: a bunch of issues with my wifi connection. Have tried a few troubleshooting techniques, but nothing has worked. Was given an error message about a driver causing problems, but only received said error once and I believe I was unable to actually uninstall the adapter's driver.

Finally, if this is of any use, here's the [wifi adapter](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/usb-adapter/archer-t9uh/) I'm using. It was working flawlessly until a few weeks ago, and literally quadrupled the speeds I was getting compared to my previous adapter, so I'm hoping I can get back to those kinds of speeds.

If you managed to read all that, thanks very much! Any and all advice is much appreciated.

Comment: WiFi issues are almost always signal quality issues. Nearby interference, competing devices, wireless extenders, etc. Make sure everything is using a current firmware and driver and make sure you’re operating only in the 5 GHz band where interference is not such a problem. Make sure the wireless extender is not broadcasting on the same SSID or using the same wireless channel. There’s just too many variables here to tell you “how to troubleshoot a WiFi issue.” Please focus your post to a single question with enough details to support a direct answer.

Comment: I have done everything I can think of to isolate the issue. I've removed the extender, I've tested when I was the only person on the network, etc.

Again the main thing that baffles me is that this adapter was working perfectly for the few months I've had it, getting great speeds and never dropping the connection.

It's just very frustrating when these issues crop up seemingly out of nowhere, and I've even had them fix themselves in the past, too, which is frustrating in its own way. 

Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: “Past performance is not indicative of future results.” The wireless landscape is continually changing. If you live in any moderately populated area there are probably dozens or hundreds of devices competing for the same airspace, not to mention interference from non-wireless electronics. You’re right, it is difficult to troubleshoot. Too difficult to write an answer up here. However, you are welcome to focus your post to specific questions that can be provided brief and direct answers, such as “how do I check my router’s firmware version.” It may take several posts to get what you need.

Comment: Otherwise, I would recommend searching out a different resource as this forum is not well suited to solving broad and complex issues.

Comment: I guess I was looking for some guidance when it comes to troubleshooting in general. Things like taking the extender out of the equation and testing the router with other devices are steps that seemed obvious enough, but other things like flushing my DNS cache were unknown to me until recently, hence me asking on a forum like this where people almost certainly know much more than me (admittedly a low bar). Even your comment saying I should ask how to check my router's firmware version - this is something that's not even on my radar, which is what I was hoping to get from this post.